# Tool for deleting specific aws resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for a tool which helps me deleting unused aws resources via tags or something in that way. I've already found the tools awsnuke and awsweeper. Unfortunately both do not meet my requirements.

Someone here got some alternatvies for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AWS Trusted Advisor has some information. But there is no build-in aws service which would provide complete view.

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: You already got some responses from /r/aws, but a serious issue here is that you've never specified your requirements or how the tools fail to meet them which seemed to be same sentiment over there.